# How an helm chart have an attribute with value contain {{ }}

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

In a helm chart, we can define value as something like {{ Values.name }}, which will be replaced by the real value defined in values.yaml.
But if the original value has the similar format such as {{name}}, when trying to install that chart, it will fail due to error that "name" is not defined.
Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: What is the purpose of using "{{name}}" as a name of something?

Comment: in some configuration files, such as grafana's dashboard json file, alert rule definition in prometheus, both of them use the {{..}} format also

Answer (score 37):

You can embed it as a literal string with backticks:

```
{{`{{ "name" }}`}}
```

Comment: This was the only suggestion that worked for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I agree that using `.Files` is good in some use cases, but this much more directly answers the question.

Answer (score 12):

You can escape double curly brackets in Go templates using `{{ "{{" }}`.

But the best way is embedding the alerting rules as separate files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}-rules
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
    prometheus: {{ template "fullname" . }}
data:
  {{ (.Files.Glob "rules/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

Comment: still cannot work. Trying to deploy the helm chart and got the error message: function "name" not defined

Comment: For non-gophers: if your template fragment is inside a string like `json: '{ "mustache": "{{ .Values.prefix }} {{ name }}" }'` you can use back ticks to quote the inner {{ (although it gets pretty messy):  `json: '{ "mustache": "{{ .Values.prefix }} {{ \`{{\` }} name {{ \`}}\` }}" }'`

Answer (score 8):

Use `'{{"{{"}}name{{"}}"}}'` for it to be read as {{name}}

Comment: This was also the way for me to add the variable in Jaeger tracesToLogsV2 in the Grafana datasource.