# Use of Helm to create Argo Workflows templates with parameters makes parsing error

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows

I'm generating Argo templates using helm and I need to use a parameter (That will be a list).

I'm trying to write it like this

```
args: {{"{{"}}inputs.parameters.args{{"}}"}}
```

The problem is that I get this error from helm:

```
install.go:178: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:195: [debug] CHART PATH: /Users/idanahal/projects/exportinno/JobSubmitterCrons/kubernetes-templates

Error: YAML parse error on photon-crons-chart/templates/job-submitter-workflow-template.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"inputs.parameters.args":interface {}(nil)}
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"inputs.parameters.args":interface {}(nil)}
YAML parse error on photon-crons-chart/templates/job-submitter-workflow-template.yaml
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/action.go:165
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Install).RunWithContext
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:259
main.runInstall
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:264
main.newTemplateCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/template.go:82
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.4.0/command.go:902
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:250
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1571
```

I have tried a lot of other option and nothing works.

I want the result would be `{{inputs.parameters.args}}` and not `"{{inputs.parameters.args}}"`

Comment: Coul you add your expected output to the quetion?

Comment: What context is this appearing in; part a `values.yaml` file, a ConfigMap, a Deployment, something else?  To confirm, you want the output to contain the literal string `{{inputs.parameters.args}}` including the curly braces and with no other expansions or processing?

Comment: Yes, and Helm won't let me because its not a valid yaml I think

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195593/how-an-helm-chart-have-an-attribute-with-value-contain ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see the outcome of the answers is: '{{ name }}' and not: {{ name }}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
args: '{{ "{{" }}inputs.parameters.args{{ "}}" }}'
```

The reason for this is that Helm and Argo both use curly braces for their templating.

Adding additional braces escapes the Helm templating syntax so that Helm doesn't try to parse it, and instead passes it directly to Kubernetes